# How display image encrypted in RSA

Tags: image, encryption, rsa

My program should encrypt image using RSA (got this part). Result of this is string (or byte array) with numbers.

My question is: How can I display encrypted image in e.g. Windows img browser? I want to show that algorithm is working.

Should I skip some part of header or add something in the beginning of file which cause that it will be treating as image?

I'm looking for answer but this what I found, won't work.

Comment: Sounds like you want to eat the cake and have it, too. Decrypt the encrypted image and compare the decrypted image with the original. Also: what did you find, even when it "didn't work"? How does it not "work"?

Comment: All I want is display encrypted bytes. I understand it that if I encode image it will be still image but messy and nothing can be see. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

When I try to display it using Image.FromStream there is System.ArgumentException

Comment: if you encrypte an image it turns into an illegible sequence of bytes which does not allow to judge its origin, be it from an image, text or random bytes - it only turns back into an image once decrypted with the appropriate key.

Comment: But I can encrypt only byte mass of file, without changing header. It gaves me some results (showing messy thing if I put e.g. value 50 in every byte after header). Problem is that it can be value up to 255 but if I'm encoding it with RSA it gaves me values above 1000000 (my keys are long numbers).

Comment: Encrypting part of a file seems stupid, especially when it comes to images where you find dozens if not hundrets of formats - each would need separate treatment (and yes, you cannot rely on file extensions). Simply replacing some pixel values with some output from RSA of image parts course does not do the trick nor can that be expected. Nor will be the length of the encrypted part necessarily be of the same size as the input (thinking of padding etc)

Comment: Yeah, it is quite stupid but it is working. I know it is not perfect but it is good for me (I got just JPEG on input). I would rather focus on encrypting part (this what You told about).
So what is the trick to convert huge numbers into smaller or how can I solve this? I have no idea. I thought about spliting RSA output or resizing image but I think it is inelegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show an encrypted image as discussed in the question and comments, you can simply generate or load some random white noise in place of the image - it wouldn't matter visually whether it's the encrypted visual information or some other noise.

An image is not encrypted, though, if you do not encrypt it in its entirety. The headers usually contain meta information about size, creation date, creation programme, authors, palettes etc - information which can be as valuable as the image itself. Using jpg, depending on the compression level chosen, and the image information, the body of the image can be of various size - a size not inevitably matched by encrypting that information. Similar argument goes for most image formats.

Additionally, as you cannot change the size (or you'll end up with buffer under- or overruns on decryption), there is no sane way to only encrypt the body of an image.

If you still want to go this unsafe way into disaster: you simply have to interpret the output of rsa as a sequence of bytes (or whatever the body of the image format you deal with) - and not as the output format as given by rsa (though I wonder, it should be bytes).

Comment: Thanks, this answer clear my mind and now I know what I'm dealing with :)